# What is " + i + " in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```js
<script>
var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
  table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(" + i + ")'><td>";
  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td><td>";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayCD(i) {
  document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
  "Artist: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Title: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Year: " + 
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Click on a CD to display album information.</p>
<p id='showCD'></p>
<table id="demo"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand what `+ i +` means inside that function. I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: What precisely is confusing? It's just string concatenation.

Comment: `str1 = "world"; str2 = "Helllo " + str1 + "!"`?

Comment: It doesn't concatenate. I don't see it concatenate the quote or anything else. When i remove it, the function stop working.

Comment: It stops working because `i` is being passed to the function `displayCD()`. When the function `displayCD()` is declared you can see that it requires a parameter. So if you delete `+ i +` then you will no longer be passing the parameter to the function and you will get an error. In your code `i` is the counter for the for loop.  So each time the for loop runs, you call `displayCD( i )`... so displayCD(0)... displayCD(1)... displayCD(2)...  i is the incrementer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside this loop, `i` is the iterator, so it starts at `0` and increases by `1` every time the loop repeats until `i` is less than than the length of `x`, at which time the loop will stop.

```
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
  table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(" + i + ")'><td>";
  table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td><td>";
  table +=  x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  table += "</td></tr>";
}
```

The line `table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(" + i + ")'><td>";` appends some HTML to the table. The `" + i + "` part inserts the iterator into the loop, so if the loop had been processed twice, `i` would be equal to `1` and the line `table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(" + i + ")'><td>";` would become `table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(1)'><td>";`.

*`+` adds strings (or numbers depending on the context) together, so `"hello " + "world" + "!"` essentially means `"hello world!"`.*

*You can also add strings to variables. For example, if `i` is equal to `7` and you write `"hello " + i + "!"`, that essentially means `"hello 7!"`. This is known as concatenation.*

*In your case, you are concatenating `i` into a function call.*

Comment: Thanks. I always call a function without a quote, like this: myFunction(sky). I'm curious why that function has quotes and plus signs around the i.

Comment: @Rostam The quotes are so that the variable isn't seen as text and the `+` signs are so that the strings are attached to the value of the variable. Also, don't forget to mark correct answers so people know which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's a concatenation, displayCD(" + i + ") will rendering displayCD(1), displayCD(2)... i refers to the variable incremented in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i refers to index there in order to pass dynamic input for each table row function displayCD will pass dynamic index in each table row . For example first row it will be displayCD('0') , second row it will be displayCD('1') and this will continue until length of the array.